# Нужно передать закодированный текст в base64

Tags: java, post, base64

У меня есть mp3 файл, который мне нужно закачать в Битрикс24.

Здесь я читаю mp3 файл, кодирую и записываю String

```
public synchronized String encodeToBase64(File file) {

        File target = convertWavToMp3(file);
        String encoded = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
            encoded = Base64.byteArrayToBase64(bytes);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.warn(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

Так я формирую url и parameters

```
    public void externalCallAttachRecord(String call_id, File file) {
        String encoded = util.encodeToBase64(file);
        String path = properties.getBitrixId() + "/"
                + properties.getBitrixOutterWebhook() + "/telephony.externalCall.attachRecord";

        String fileName = file.getName().split(".wav")[0].concat(".mp3");

        String params = "CALL_ID=" + call_id
                + "&FILENAME=" + fileName
                + "&FILE_CONTENT[0]=" + fileName
                + "&FILE_CONTENT[1]=" + encoded;

        String jsonString = postRequest(path, params);
        log.debug("externalCallAttachRecord reply is {}", jsonString);
}
```

Ну и собственно сам POST запрос, при помощи которого, отправляю все в битрикс

```
private String postRequest(String path, String params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://" + properties.getBitrixDomain() + "/rest/" + path);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            byte[] data = params.getBytes();
            os.write(data);
//            os.flush();

  ... тут идет код, обрабатывающий ответ сервера...

        } catch (
                Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Так вот сервер присылает мне ответ:

{"error":"","error_description":"File content is not properly encoded. Base64 encoding is expected."}
мол содержимое файла не закодировано в base64.

Вот у меня подозрение, что здесь происходит что-то не так , как я себе представляю:

```
os.write(data);
```

Ну не может, же `os.write(data)` раскодировать base64...

Comment: Полагаю, что дело в неправильном `Content-Type`. Там должен быть не `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`, а судя по остальным параметрам `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный ну теперь мне битрикс отвечает ОК, а только в самом битриксе у записи стоит длительность -0.00сек и жмешь на play ни чего не происходит...

Comment: Попробуйте убрать или исправить `Content-Length`, который у вас не учитывает длину файла в Base64.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный если убрать, то снова ругается, что содержимое не закодировано. Но почему не учитывает? ведь `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));` а переменная `String params = "CALL_ID=" + call_id
                + "&FILENAME=" + fileName
                + "&FILE_CONTENT[0]=" + fileName
                + "&FILE_CONTENT[1]=" + encoded;` включает переменную `String encoded = Base64.byteArrayToBase64(bytes);`

Comment: Как правильно посчитать длину передаваемого контента?

Comment: Да, считаете вы вроде бы правильно. Я просто ошибочно решил, что `data` посылается в дополнении к `params`, а это и есть `params` в виде массива байтов. Название файла у вас на английском?

Comment: @РостиславКрасный да, на английском. Проблема у меня скорее всего с настройкой параметров POST запроса. Я параллельно открыл вопрос на форуме Битрикса [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum48/topic113823/) Там один парень отправил мои же данные POST запросом но через PHP скрипт и у него все ОК...

Comment: Я вот думаю, что в моей переменной params, только часть строки закодирована base64, может мне нужно как-то разделить кодированные и не кодированные данные?

Comment: Найдите другую возможность, при которой это работает, например через браузер. Затем посмотрите (снифером или дебагером браузера по F11) что реально передаётся в обоих случаях и найдите разницу.